# Proof of Euler Characteristic for Sphere

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, manifolds, surfaces

> **Theorem 1.** All cell decompositions of a sphere $S$ have Euler characteristic 2.

This is well-known, but I had this idea for an intuitive proof: for any cell decomposition $\Gamma$ with $V$ vertices, $E$ edges and $F$ faces, let $G(\Gamma) = 1 - (V - E + F)/2$. $G(\Gamma)$ is the genus of the surface represented by $\Gamma$ (if the surface is closed and orientable), but suppose we don't know that yet.

Suppose we have two cell decompositions $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$, and we glue them together by removing one face from each and gluing the exposed edges together, like the connected sum $\#$. It can be verified that $G(\Gamma\#\Gamma') = G(\Gamma) + G(\Gamma')$.

Pardon the lack of rigor but I had the vague idea of using the fact that $G(S) = G(S\# S) = 2G(S)$ thus $G(S) = 0$, and Theorem 1 immediately follows. This is an *intuitive* proof because I allow the assumption that $S\# S = S$. But even so this seems to be circular because I first have to show that $G$ depends on the surface, not the cell decomposition. I have no idea how to do that without proving Theorem 1 beforehand.

Does this vague idea have any value?

Comment: If you know that $G$ does not depend on the cell decomposition, it seems to be simpler to draw a triangulation of the sphere and then compute $\chi(\mathbb{S}^2)$.

Comment: Dear @Seirios : Do you think you might be able to bang out a solution for this? The Crusade of Answers would really like to see it come off the unanswered questions list. Thanks for considering it!

Comment: @rschwieb: I tried to formulate a reasonable answer.

Comment: @Seirios Great: thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know in order to show that the Euler characteristic we compute does not depend on the cell decomposition is to use [homology groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Topological_definition): it shows that $\chi(S)$ depends only on the homotopy type of $S$. Afterwards, it is sufficient to chose a nice cell decomposition, namely a triangulation with just four vertices, and check that the associated Euler characteristic is 2.

However, if you are just interested in triangulations rather than cell decompositions, thanks to a well-chosen stereographic projection, the property you mention is equivalent to [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula) on planar graphs. More details may be found [here](http://chiasme.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/euler-poincare-characteristic-i-eulers-formula-and-graph-theory/) for example.

Comment: I believe another approach is to show that $\chi$ is unchanged under taking a subdivision, and then show that any two triangulations have a common subdivision.

Comment: I think the argument works, but it is terribly tedious!